# use php to select * from table where 2 entries have to match

Tags: php, mysqli

what i want is to be able to select all from a table where bout x = x and y = y,
if x = y and y = y i dont want it count. pritty much 2 entries where bouth have to match. I know about `SELECT * FROM 'messages' WHERE read = '0', id = $id;` but doesnt that select bouth rows where `id = $id` and `read = '0'` ?

The whole point of this is to display `x` messages that the specific user have recived but not yet opened, might be a better way to do it but this is what ive come to so far:

```
<?php
    $id = htmlentities($_SESSION['user']['id'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
    $db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "password", "database") or die ("Could not connect to database");

    $inboxquery = mysqli_query ($db, "SELECT * FROM message WHERE to_id='$id'");
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($inboxquery, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
            $to_id = $row['to_id'];
            $read = $row['read'];
        }


    $x = mysqli_num_rows($result)

    if($x == >0){
        echo"<span>".$value." <a class='a' href='/Inbox'> Inbox</span>";
    }else{
        echo"<span><i class='fa fa-inbox'></i></span> <a class='a' href='/Inbox'> Inbox";
    }
?>
```

Comment: no $result and $value are not yet set to anything. the code is not finished

Comment: `where` is a boolean test. if the entire `where` expression evaluates to `true`, then the record being considered becomes part of the result set. if it's false, then the record is excluded.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I fully understand the question but assuming an unread message has a zero in the read column, this should work..

```
$inboxquery = mysqli_query ($db, "SELECT * FROM message WHERE read = 0 AND to_id='$id'");
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand your question correctly, but if you want to show rows that have read = 0 or id = id (so show both rows that have either one of them), simply use OR:

```
SELECT * FROM message WHERE to_id = '$id' OR read = 0
```

Comment: I dont know how to formulate the question in english but i pritty much want bout id and read to match, so only select rows where `to_id = $id` and `read = 0`

Comment: @Saskia seems we both have the same idea yet a different interpretations of the same question. I think in this case, your approach would show one user unread message counts for ALL users, and I don't think that is the desired result

Comment: nope, several users are registered and that is one of my concerns, that and if it only checks the last message that was sent.